# Accessing and running a function on a JQuery Set

Tags: jquery

I am trying to access and run a function on a jQuery set why do I get the error message in the console

```
TypeError: $(...).get(...).hide is not a function
```

Below is the code I am running.

```
$("div").get(0).hide(); 

 <div class="local"><p>A</p></div>
 <div class="local-"><p>B</p></div>
 <div class="international"><p>C</p></div> 
 <div class="local"><p>D</p></div>
 <div class="local-"><p>E</p></div>
 <div class="international"><p>F</p></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use [`.eq(index)`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) instead of [`.get(index)`](https://api.jquery.com/get/)

```
$("div").eq(0).hide();
```

`.get()` will yield you the underlying `node object` based on supplied index, not a jquery object. So a native `node object` will not have a function called `.hide()` in its proto chain. That is why the error is appearing in your case.